# Clear prepared statement cache in AWS Keyspaces on table definition change

Tags: cassandra, prepared-statement, amazon-keyspaces

Is there an easy way to clear prepared statement cache in AWS Keyspaces?
Traditional tricks used on manual cassandra nodes cannot be used in the AWS Cloud.

In Cassandra, if the table definition changes, this cache seems to be cleared. But I found some cases where AWS Keyspaces does not when you modify the table on columns used in a former prepared statement.